# I want to create a page transition once I scroll to the bottom of the page

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I am in the process of redesigning my portfolio and one mechanic I want to do is have my portfolio page transition to another page by scrolling. The idea is once the page scrolls to the bottom, it immediately transitions to the new page. The current javascript I have transitions to a new page after it times out at a certain point which doesn't make the transition seamless.

```
<script>
  window.onscroll = function(ev) {
  if ((window.innerHeight + window.pageYOffset ) >= document.body.offsetHeight) {
  setTimeout(function(){
  window.location.href = "https://www.google.com";
  }, 5000);
  }
  };
</script>
 <body>
<h1>This is page 1</h1>
<img src="https://picsum.photos/seed/picsum/1200/800">
  
 </body>
```

If there anyway what I am requesting can be achieved using the onscroll feature?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Could you provide a complete and reproducible example? Including necessary CSS, HTML, and JS
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a setTimeout function to wait for a certain amount of time before transitioning to the new page, you can simply transition to the new page once the user has scrolled to the bottom of the page.

```
<script>
  window.onscroll = function(ev) {
    if ((window.innerHeight + window.pageYOffset) >= document.body.offsetHeight) {
      window.location.href = "https://www.google.com";
    }
  };
</script>

<body>
  <h1>This is page 1</h1>
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/seed/picsum/1200/800">
  <div style="height: 2000px;"></div>
</body>
```